# Pandas - Recursively look for children in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, children

Consider the below dataframe:

```
    id1    id2
0   aaa    111
1   bbb    222
2   333    ccc
3   999    zzz
4   ccc    111
5   888    zzz
6   zzz    222
7   ddd    888
8   eee    888
```

How can I recursively get a dataframe for every match of all the children and all of their grandchildren of a given input, in my case, input = [111, 222] 
i.e
Parent1: 111
Child1: aaa
Child2: ccc (from row 4)
Child of Child2: 333 (from row 2)

Parent2: 222
Child1: bbb
Child2: zzz (from row 6)
ChildA of Child2: 888 (from row 5)
ChildB of Child2: 999 (from row 3)
Child_i of ChildA: ddd(from row 8)
Child_ii of ChildA: eee (from row 7)

the expected output for every level (parent->child->child of child) would be:

```
### for i = 111
# parent level
     id1    id2
0    aaa    111
1    ccc    111

# child level
     id1    id2
0    333    ccc


### for i = 222
# parent level
     id1    id2
0    bbb    222
1    zzz    222

# child level
     id1    id2
0    888    zzz
1    999    zzz

# child of child level
     id1    id2
0    ddd    888    
1    eee    888
```

I tried:

```
parents = [111, 222]

while len(parents) != 0:
    for i in parents:
        children = df[df['id2'].apply(lambda x: i in str(x))][['id1', 'id2']]
        print(children) #print dataframe of match
    parents = children['id1']
```

but it doesn't go all the way through, I thought of changing i in lambda to a list comprehension but didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: What is the expected dataframe?

Comment: for every match, just df[['id1', 'id2']], I can then concatenate them

Comment: @bloo Please update the question with your expected output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to print an indented graph, you could use a simple recursive function:

```
def desc(i, indent=0):
    print(' '*indent + i)
    for j in df.loc[df['id2'] == i, 'id1']:
        desc(j, indent + 2)

for i in ('111', '222'): desc(i)
```

With the example df, it gives:

```
111
  aaa
  ccc
    333
222
  bbb
  zzz
    999
    888
      ddd
      eee
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for! I can change the format on my end. My only question is whether it will go down the hierarchy until there is no children (or children of children) for as many levels, because my actual dataframe is hundreds of thousands of rows and although I do see an extra level on the print on my end I was wondering if it stopped there because of the code or because there is no other children.

Comment: This one has no limit on levels, so it should go down until an element has no child.

Comment: Thank you so much, I need to study this now :) I am not sure where I got mixed up in my logic and my code wasn't working

Comment: @bloo: the difference is that this code is recursive: the function `desc` calls itself. Your code only contained loops.

Comment: I now see how I was trying to achieve that with loops rather than a recursive function, was working on it for some time and got tunnel vision. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The `result` dataframe will also contain NaNs, but if you want to drop them use `result.dropna()`:

```py
from io import StringIO
d = StringIO("""
ix    id1    id2
0   aaa    111
1   bbb    222
2   333    ccc
3   999    zzz
4   ccc    111
5   888    zzz
6   zzz    222
7   ddd    888
8   eee    888
""")

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(d, sep='\s+', index_col='ix')

df.columns

result = (
    df.rename(columns={'id2': 'id_parent', 'id1': 'id_child'})
    .merge(df.set_index('id2'), how='left', left_on='id_child', right_index=True)
    .rename(columns={'id1': 'id_grandchild'})
)

result
```

Here's for example a way to list all grandchildren:

```py
result.dropna().groupby('id_parent')['id_grandchild'].agg(list).reset_index()
```

Here's a way to create a look-up dictionary that contains all the grandchildren for an individual:

```py
dict_parents = result.dropna().groupby('id_parent')['id_grandchild'].agg(list).to_dict()
# e.g. try: print(dict_parents['222'])
```

Here's a way to get the result for specific individuals:

```py
specific_ids = ['111', '222']

result = (
    df[df['id2'].isin(specific_ids)].rename(columns={'id2': 'id_parent', 'id1': 'id_child'})
    .merge(df.set_index('id2'), how='left', left_on='id_child', right_index=True)
    .rename(columns={'id1': 'id_grandchild'})
)

result.dropna()
```

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that I am not trying to change the format of the dataframe. I am trying to extract the information on the back of an input.

Comment: Hmm, are you trying to get this? `result[['id_parent', 'id_grandchild']].dropna()` Your question still mentions that you want a dataframe...

Comment: The idea was that there is an input or a list of inputs and then for every input in the list, I look for its child in the dataframe and then for the child of that child and so on until there is no child and then move to the next input. I would then get a dataframe for every match which I can then concatenate at a later stage.

Comment: If I understand your process correctly, after concatenation  you would receive dataframe `result`. If the problem is to subset it to specific individuals, then you can impose that restriction before the merge, see my updated answer.